# RVIZ/Gazebo plugin development workflow

Tags: rviz, gazebo-plugin, ros-noetic, pluginlib, rviz-plugins

I am developing a Rviz plugin under ros-noetic.

My current workflow is: modify code -> compile code -> start rviz -> stop rviz -> modify code ...

I could only get RVIZ (or plugin lib class loader) to reload the shared object file by restarting the entire RVIZ.

Is it possible to reload the shared object without restarting rviz? Or are there any other workflows that make plugin development less frustrating?

All suggestions are welcome.